# How to style jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Open http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

You can select a date.
I need to style the calendar so that when you click next the selected day will get highlighted on the next months ( when you click back and forth)

Comment: So you want the same date number of the next month to be highlighted? Like if the calendar says "January 4" and you click the next month button, the date will become "February 4"? What about Jan 31 -> Feb ??

Answer (score 1):

Just use FireBug or a similar tool to check the css classes and properties and customize them..

Answer (score 0):

The style of jQuery-ui widget is define in the css file you downloaded with the pack of scripts
You can choose the theme you want in the page to customize download

Answer (score 0):

You are not just styling the selected day of the next month to be highlighted. You should actually **MOVE** the selection to that day of next month. You could do it by handling the `onChangeMonthYear` event